# How to suppress http.client exceptions logging during requests.get() request with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-requests

I am using Python3 and making requests with the following code:

```
      try:
        resp = self.s.get(url, proxies=self.proxies)
        return resp.text
    except ConnectTimeout:
        self.logger.exception('{}: connection timeout!'.format(self.name))
    except ConnectionError:
        self.logger.exception('{}: ConnectionError!'.format(self.name))
    except RemoteDisconnected:
        self.logger.exception('{}: RemoteDisconnected'.format(self.name))
    except MaxRetryError:
        self.logger.exception('{}: MaxRetryError'.format(self.name))
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.exception(e)
```

And if I get exception during session().get(url, proxies=proxies), I get the following in the log file:

```
2018-04-20 17:14:27 | RF5MR: ConnectionError!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.thesite.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /asdzxcqwe/2058706 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/fetcher.py", line 417, in make_request
    resp = self.s.get(url, proxies=self.proxies)
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 218, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/scripts/this-is-my-app/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.thesite.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /asdzxcqwe/2058706 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))
```

But what I want to get is only that string logged:

**2018-04-20 17:14:27 | RF5MR: ConnectionError!**

Could you please point me where my mistake is and how could I suppress those exception texts and get only the one I want to log?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `self.logger.exception`, call `self.logger.error`.

`exception` logs the message and the trace back. All of the other log methods only log the message at the priority given specific to the method.

See [the documentation on the logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).